# Cannot GET after middleware using Express and next() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I'm trying to apply a middleware that modifies the "req" parameter, it works perfectly until I finally use the next() function. This is the code from the middleware:

**auth.js**

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const auth = (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const token = req.header("x-auth-token");
        if(!token) return res.status(401).json({msg: "No authentication token, access denied"});
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SIGNIN_KEY);
        if(!verified) return res.status(401).json({msg: "Token verification failed, authorization denied"});
        req.user = verified._id;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
}
```

This middleware is executed in the users controller, as follows:

**userController.js**

```
export const userIndex = asyncHandler(auth, async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user);
    res.json({
        displayName: user.displayName,
        id: user._id,
    });
})
```

And after that I associate this function to the user routes:

**userRoutes.js**

```
import { googleLogin, tokenIsValid, userIndex } from "../controllers/userController.js";
import express from 'express'
const router = express.Router()

router.route('/getUser').get(userIndex)
router.route('/googlelogin').post(googleLogin)
router.route('/tokenIsValid').post(tokenIsValid)

export default router
```

```
import connectDB from './backend/config/db.js'
import userRoutes from './backend/routes/userRoutes.js'
import dotenv  from 'dotenv'
import express from 'express'

connectDB() // Ejecuto la conexión a la base de datos

dotenv.config() // Llamo a las variables de .env

const app = express() // Defino el servidor

app.use(express.json()); // Permite que el servidor entienda los datos enviados en formato JSON
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes) // Creo las rutas para el usuario

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000 // Defino un puerto para el servidor

// Ejecuto el servidor
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`La aplicación está corriendo en entorno de ${process.env.NODE_ENV} sobre el puerto ${PORT}`))
```

The problem occurs when I call this route, it will always return 404 error:

[image: Error Picture]

I think that this error is happening bc of the next() function.

Any clue ?

Thanks guys !!

Comment: What is `asyncHandler`?

Comment: What is asyncHandler ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler
Simple middleware for handling exceptions inside of async express routes and passing them to your express error handlers.

@Bergi

Comment: Looks like you need to pass the middleware to express' `.post()`, not into `asyncHandler` which takes only a single argument

Comment: Same result using: app.post(auth, async (req, res) => {} ... @Bergi https://prnt.sc/26mprr5

Comment: It's `app.post(auth, asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {…}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the package that you are using, it only expects one function as a parameter, but you are passing more than one and this will cause the error. I would change your code in the following way:

**userController.js**

```
export const userIndex = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user);
    res.json({
        displayName: user.displayName,
        id: user._id,
    });
})
```

**userRoutes.js**

```
import { googleLogin, tokenIsValid, userIndex } from "../controllers/userController.js";
import express from 'express'
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/getUser', auth, userIndex)
router.post('/googlelogin', googleLogin)
router.post('/tokenIsValid', tokenIsValid)

export default router
```

Comment: Thanks mann !!! This solved my problem.

Comment: Great, this week I will create a similar package to make a wrapper for async function and if you can test it, it would be great.

Comment: For sure !! Just send the link :D